# Why did Hagrid stab Flitwick in this scene?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Goblet of Fire (2005)*, Maxime speaks to Hagrid about her horses:

> MAXIME: But you know, Monsieur Hagrid... they drink only single-malt
> whiskey.

Then Hagrid stab Flitwick with a fork:

[image]

Comment: No particular help from the script; **DUMBLEDORE**: *Not to worry Madame Maxime, our gamekeeper Hagrid's more than capable of seeing to them.* **MADAME MAXIME**: *But you know Monsieur Hagrid, they drink only single malt whiskey.* **The man seated next to Hagrid yelps. Hagrid has stabbed a fork into his hand.** **MAN**:                          You idiot! - http://nldslab.soe.ucsc.edu/charactercreator/film_corpus/film_20100519/all_imsdb_05_19_10/Harry-Potter-and-the-Goblet-of-Fire.html

Comment: Numerous people have pointed out on Reddit, etc that Flitwick moved Hagrid's dish out of the way and hence his stabbing was largely self-inflicted.  https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/js1vo5/flitwick_was_the_reason_hagrid_stabbed_the_fork/

Comment: Hagrid had just had it up to here with those %^&%* Ewoks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just meant as a comedy scene to highlight the fact that [Hagrid is smitten with Madam Maxime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldktx4nAdno), and isn't paying attention to his surroundings.

Comment: Although this is probably correct, can you offer any evidence to back it up, aside from your own personal opinion?

Comment: It also comically undermines Dumbledore's assurance of Hagrid's competence in looking after and feeding animals, by showing that Hagrid can't even feed *himself* without causing collateral damage. ;)

Comment: @Valorum Well, I don't have any evidence, but I can explain the logic behind my speculation: The filmmakers needed to develop Hagrid's relationship with Madam Maxime quickly, as (IIRC) they don't get any other proper scenes together before the Yule Ball. So this is the only scene to give a glimpse of Hagrid's feelings (unlike the books, where he courts her at every chance he gets).

Comment: @Valorum -- All the evidence we really need is right on Hagrid's face. The clip I linked to is, if I recall correctly, right after Madame Maxine mentions that her horses drink only whisky. Hagrid's eyes are focused on Maxine, and he just jabs his fork without paying attention. We know from context that he is, in fact, smitten with Madame Maxine, as he is later seen to have combed his hair, gotten some flowers and eventually dances with her at the Yule Ball.

Comment: @Righter - These comments sound like the sort of thing that should be in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It was unintentional. He didn't know Flitwick's hand was there. Hagrid confused the locations a bit.